# SMB file access behind NAT policy in firewall

Tags: windows, active-directory, nat, server-message-block, sonicwall

I've got an file server behind a firewall (different network from my production network), so my computers are reaching files using a NAT policy in my Firewall.

My users are having troubles and lost connection in file explorer when they work with files behind the firewall.

My firewall is an Sonicwall TZ300.
I already change the TTL in the access rules to UP the limit, I changed the MTU outbound the firewall to have smaller packet than my LAN network (client computers).

What can I set more?
Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Sorry mate, SMB does not work that well over NAT (by protocol design), there is a dependency on the client IP. It works fine while there is 1 user, and it starts failing when there are more. It simply needs to communicate with either original IPs or 1-to-1 mappings, otherwise it fails to determine "who asks for what".
I assume you mean PAT when you say NAT :)

Comment: Ok thank you.
Basically I do PAT for the port translating, and NAT. :)

Behind my firewall I've got 3 servers, so I only NAT my FW ip to one server.